# UIScrollView distribute UIButtons Horizontally

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a `UIScrollView` that will expand depending on how many buttons it is due to display. It will always round up to the nearest 320 multiple.

So, if the `UIScrollView` will receive 3 buttons it will be 320px horizontal, if it received 6 then 640px, 9 is 960.

What I need to do is distribute the `UIButtons` across this `UIScrollView` evenly.. However I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

My `UIButtons` measure 80 pixels horizontally.

Could somebody help me get my head round this?

**Update/Clarification: I have no problem setting the UIScrollView's width. This has been done. I am looking for info on how to distribute the 'UIButtons' within the 'UIScrollView'..**

Comment: Did you mean increasing the scrollable area?

Comment: just need to change the contentisize of scrollView

Comment: Are you using paging in scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

```
[theScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320/640/960, theScrollView.frame.size.height)];
```

Comment: Heyy there,   maybe I wasn't clear. I know how to create the correct scrollview size, I am looking for information on how to distribute the UIButton's across the UIScrollView..  Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
   //considering a margin of 10 pts on either edges and a additional 10 pts on each side of button
```

Add the buttons like below:

```
for(int i=0; i< buttonCount;i++){
    CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake( 10 + i*(80+10+10) +10 , buttonY, 80, buttonHeight );
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:<type>];
    button.frame = buttonFrame;
}

//To set the scrollable area

[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake( 10 + buttonCount*(80+10+10) +10, 0 )];
//left margin +  buttonCount x (buttonWidth + leftButtonMargin+rightButtonMargin) + right margin
```

This should give you an almost evenly distributed buttons according to the number of buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:Use MyScrollView.pagingEnabled=YES.

```
int PageNum=0;

if(TotalButtons%3 >0)
{
  pageNum=TotalButtons/3;
  pageNum++; 
}
else{
PageNum=TotalButtons/3;
}

[MyScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320*pageNum, MyScrollView.frame.size.height)];
```

Add Buttons according to the width and spacing you want on the scrollview.

**Edit:**

```
 int x=56;
    int y=60;

    for(int i=1;i<= 60;i++)
    {
        UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        button.frame=CGRectMake(x, y, 200, 120);
        button.tag=i;
        // [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Video-%d",i+1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"220x200.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [VideoStoreScroll addSubview:button];

        if(i%6==0)
        {
            count++;

            x=(count-1)*VideoStoreScroll.frame.size.width+56;

            y=50;
        }
        else
        {
            if(i%3==0)
            {
                x=(count-1)*VideoStoreScroll.frame.size.width+56;
                y=y+190;
            }
            else
            {
                x=x+256;
            }
        }
    }

    VideoStoreScroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(x-56, 480);
    VideoStoreScroll.contentOffset=CGPointMake(0, 0);
```

Here I am using six buttons horizontally on scroll per page.You can work for three following this.

Answer (score 0):

First take all the buttons in an array..lets say `buttonsArray`

```
int spacing = 10;       // Adjust according to you requirement
int buttonWidth = 100;  // Adjust according to you requirement
int buttonHeight = 100; // Adjust according to you requirement
int count = 0;

for (UIButton *thisButton in buttonsArray) {
    [thisButton setFrame:CGRectMake(spacing*(count+1)+count*buttonWidth, 20, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)];
    count++;
}

[theScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake([[buttonsArray lastObject]frame].origin.x+[[buttonsArray lastObject]frame].size.width+spacing, 0)];
```

**Hope this will help you.**  **I have tested it..working fine...**